# Why does friction act against the direction of rolling motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, work, free-body-diagram

> To stimulate car accidents auto manufacturers study the collision of moving cars with mounted springs of different spring constants. Consider a typical simulation with a car of mass $1000\ \mathrm{kg}$ moving with a speed $5\ \mathrm{m/s}$ on a smooth road and colliding with a horizontally mounted spring of spring constant $6.25\times 10^3$. What is the maximum compression of the spring
>
> 1. when there is no friction and
> 2. when $\mu=0.5$?
>
> [image: free-body diagram of car and spring]
>
> $$\Delta K = K_f - K_i = 0 - \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
>   The work done by the net force is
>   $$W = -\frac{1}{2}kx_m^2 - \mu mgx_m$$
>   Equating we have
>   $$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}kx_m^2 + \mu mgx_m$$
>   Now $\mu mg = 0.5\times 10^3\times 10 = 5\times 10^3\ \mathrm{N}$ (taking $g = 10.0\ \mathrm{m\,s^{-2}}$). After rearranging the above equation we obtain the following quadratic equation in the unknown $x_m$.
>   $$\begin{gather}
> k x_m^2 + 2\mu m g x_m - mv^2 = 0 \\
> x_m = \frac{-\mu mg + \bigl[\mu^2 m^2 g^2 + mkv^2\bigr]^{1/2}}{k}
> \end{gather}$$
>   where we take the positive square root since $x_m$ is positive. Putting in numerical values we obtain
>   $$x_m = 1.35\ \mathrm{m}$$
>   which, as expected, is less than the result in Example 6.8.

Now the first part is easy. We are able to find the kinetic energy which is converted to P.E. at max compression. so we get $12500\ \mathrm{J} = 0.5kx^2$ and then we get the compression $x$ as 2.00 metres.

But what about the second part? In this first and foremost lets consider the FBD which is my main problem in this question. why is the friction acting in the positive x direction? If the wheels of the car are rolling then I would think the friction should be in the direction of the motion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll let you discuss about steady velocity rolling.

However, the problem takes friction to $x^+$ because when the car makes contact with the spring, the car must slow down. Here the wheels are rotating counter-clockwise. What the floor "feels" is a force towards the left, $x^-$, therefore it responds with a force towards $x^+$. This happens JUST when the car is being accelerated to $x^+$ by the spring.